# Dragging from an inherited QTableView

Tags: qt

I have in my app a table view called "partsview" which is descended from a `QTableView`, this is on the main form. The relevant header code looks like:

```
class partsiew : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit partsview(QWidget *parent = 0);
public:
    QStringList mimeTypes() const;
    QMimeData *mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const;
};
```

I have also added the following into the constructor of "partsview":

```
this->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
this->setDragEnabled(true);
this->setAcceptDrops(true);
this->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
```

though the last two are probably not needed.

When dragging, I can pick up a row and drag it to a target - a `QTreeView` - and I get the appropriate cursor and even a `dropMimeData` event is fired on the `treeview`.

However, the row and column values in the `dropMimeData()` method are always -1 and the two methods in the "partsview" are not called.

I'm guessing that the first error may have something to do with the second.  Have I declared the `mimeType()` and `mimeData()` methods correctly for them to be called during a drag operation.

I have been following this page in the documentation [QT4.6 - Using Model/View Classes](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/model-view-dnd.html#using-model-view-classes)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link for the most recent documentation on it:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views

I recently worked on some code for doing an internal move of cells on a single table, but while I was researching it, I found some other useful links.

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/14197

I used the code in the above link and translated it to use `QTableView` instead of `QTableWidget`:

```
void MyTableView::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    // TODO: switch to using EyeTrackerModel::dropMimeData instead
    QPoint old_coordinates = QPoint(-1,-1);
    int dropAction = event->dropAction();
    if(currentIndex().isValid()) //Check if user is not accessing empty cell
    {
        old_coordinates = QPoint( currentIndex().row(), currentIndex().column() );
    }

    QTableView::dropEvent(event);
    qDebug() << "Detected drop event...";
    event->acceptProposedAction();
    if( this->indexAt(event->pos()).isValid() && old_coordinates != QPoint(-1, -1))
    {
        qDebug() << "Drop Event Accepted.";
        qDebug() << "Source: " << old_coordinates.x() << old_coordinates.y()
                 << "Destination: " << this->indexAt(event->pos()).row()
                 << this->indexAt(event->pos()).column()
                 << "Type: " << dropAction;

        emit itemDropped( old_coordinates.x(), old_coordinates.y(),
                          this->indexAt(event->pos()).row(),
                          this->indexAt(event->pos()).column(),
                          dropAction);
    }
    // resize rows and columns right after a move!
    this->doAdjustSize();
}
```

Even though the following answer is for Python, it still helped me when checking for what I could be missing.

[QT: internal drag and drop of rows in QTableView, that changes order of rows in QTableModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842342/qt-internal-drag-and-drop-of-rows-in-qtableview-that-changes-order-of-rows-in)

Here are some code snippets from my recent project related to drag and drop.  I think you have most of them already, but I included them below for completeness.

```
QAbstractTableModel::dropMimeData(const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)

Qt::ItemFlags QAbstractTableModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(index)
//    if(index.isValid())
        return Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
//    else
//        return Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
}

QAbstractTableView(QWidget *parent) :
    QTableView(parent)
{
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    setDefaultDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your full answer, phyatt.  However, it doesn't answer my question - well not directly anyway.  I'm more stuck on the start of drag end of things than the drop.  Though I'm so new to Qt, I may be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: So there is a lot in there about supporting drag and drop. I found a good example here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-puzzle-example.html  Try to match up all of the drag and drop elements they included in your model or modify their model to be yours.  You should be able to find the example in `Qt Creator > Welcome > Examples`.

Comment: Thanks, phyatt - I have looked at that example, I'll take another look.